# How to implement an input of time (or dates with times) ranges dynamically?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, collections, .net-4.0

I'd like to enhance my C# .NET 4.0 **multithreaded** WPF application by dynamic adding of time rages (`BeginTime+EndTime` pairs for each, of multiple, range).
And the multiple entered by a user (from 0 to N) time ranges should be:

- shown, i.e. presented to a user (my thought is about a ListBox or two dependent on each other listboxes)
- CRUD-ed  (Created-Read-Updated-Deleted)

I looked through 3d-party commercial `TimePicker`s or `DataTimePicker`s, creating my own custom and user controls for implementing `TimePicker` and `DateTimePicker` controls...  but still couldn't decide how to better proceed with it.

What would be **better to use** for it - a `custom control` or a `user control` and in which composition/combination (which control inside which another one - ListBox, ListView, etc.)?
Which underlying collection(s), model?

I'd appreciate any advice on how to implement it

**Update:**
If this would help to understand...
I have a WPF application that is trading at stock exchange but the user should be able to choose customizable multiple periods of time for real-time and emulation (the orders to buy and sell are shown but not sent to stock exchange) trading.  Well, this a little bit more complicated since different algorithms are being used during different period of times but the problem is that I'd like to give a user possibilities to enter configurable time periods.

This, periods of time, is now done by hard-coding, without any user interaction.

Comment: is it possible for you to show a rough sketch/image of the control, it will help in better  understanding of the question

Comment: @Amitd, it is my question: how to implement dynamic adding of time values which will be shown, updated (removed-deleted-added-changed). The part of it is which controls to use, and/or how to compose them

Comment: I always love a good time rage.

Comment: Make an example, do a sketch, anything that makes it clearer what you are after, because your text is really hard to understand...

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `DateTimePicker` and/or the `DateTimeUpDown` from the Extended WPF Toolkit™:
http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/.

And for time ranges use the Time Period Library for .NET by Jani Giannoudis:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/168662/Time-Period-Library-for-NET

Edit:

For UI arrangement you could use a `ListBox` binded to an `ObservableCollection<TimePeriod>`

```
<ListBox Name="listBox">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate >
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <xctk:DateTimePicker Value="{Binding Start}" Format="ShortTime" />
                <xctk:DateTimePicker Value="{Binding End}" Format="ShortTime" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>

public class TimePeriod
{
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
}

void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ObservableCollection<TimePeriod> collection = new ObservableCollection<TimePeriod>();
    collection.Add(new TimePeriod {Start = DateTime.Now - TimeSpan.FromHours(5), End = DateTime.Now});
    collection.Add(new TimePeriod {Start = DateTime.Now, End = DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromHours(5)});
    listBox.ItemsSource = collection;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for Time Period Library. I did not see it. Though the question is more how to arrange GUI in WPF

Comment: @Fulproof I added an example of how to implement a listbox of time periods.